# Workaround to not create new layer

Tags: arcpy, spatial-statistics, performance

I have a working code (shown at the bottom). The problem is process time is about 12 seconds for each loop. If I want to use this for the whole data I have (about 1 million points), it would take about half year. I think the problem is the following:

```
arcpy.GANeighborhoodSelection_ga(inFile, "neighbor2", pointcoord, "1", "1","5", "5", "0", "One sector")
```

this tool always creates a layer for its output, so if I want use it, I have to delete the layer after I got the information I needed. I think the problem is that it  constantly makes a new layer, which takes a lot of time.

I wonder If it's possible to force it to use the same layer somehow

```
import arcpy
inFile = "C:\\Users\\Geri\\Desktop\\Sync\\arcpy\\inverz2b.shp"
inFile2 = "C:\\Users\\Geri\\Desktop\\Sync\\arcpy\\inverz3b.shp"
n=0
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inFile2, "3blayer")
for num in range(0,4):
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("3blayer", "NEW_SELECTION","FID = %s" % n)
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("3blayer"):
        x = row.X_Easting
        y = row.Y_Northing
        z = row.Z_Elevatio
        ratio = row.ratio
    pointcoord = str(x) + " " + str(y)
    arcpy.GANeighborhoodSelection_ga(inFile, "neighbor2", pointcoord, "1", "1","5", "5", "0", "One sector")
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("neighbor2"):
        x2 = row.X_Easting
        y2 = row.Y_Northing
        z2 = row.Z_Elevatio
    newx = x-((x-x2)/2)
    newy = y-((y-y2)/2)
    newz = z2-((z2-z)*ratio)
    print x, y, z, x2, y2, z2, newx, newy, newz
    n+=1
    arcpy.Delete_management("neighbor2")
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to overwrite the "neighbor2 " layer for every loop?

Comment: Yes, or anything that could reduce the process time.

Comment: Use definition query on 3blayer instead of SelectByAttribute. Use arcpy.da.TableToNumpyArray to read both tables instead of SearchCursor, or use arcpy.da.SearchCursor at least. I don’t think you have to delete “neighbour2” everytime. It is just a layer, not new feature dataset

Comment: Moreover all of this can be replaced by single spatial join, because this is what your neighbourhood selection does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

I used the [Generate Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00080000001n000000) instead the arcpy.GANeighborhoodSelection_ga.
This process is much faster and got every information I needed in a table. After it as @FelixIP recommended, I could use spatial join to finish all remaining process.